# LDAP query doesn't show members from a trusted domain

Tags: ldap, search, trust-relationship

I have two domain ***A*** (W2K8 machine) and ***B*** (W2K12 machine) with an external non-transitive relationship with each other.

I created a Security Local Domain group ***SLDG*** on *A*. Then I created a Security Universal Group ***SUG*** on *B*. Lastly I added *SUG* as a member of *SLDG* on *A*, ***User1*** as member of *SLDG* on *A* and ***User2*** as member of *SUG* on *B*.

I run the following query to the server *A* using the global catalog port:

```
(memberOf=CN=SLD,ou=Groups,dc=mydc,dc=local)
```

In the results I can see ***User1*** and the *FSP* (Foreign Security Principal) object but I can't see the ***SUG*** group.

What might be missing in my configuration ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm stuck exactly there.

Comment: No this configuration never worked. I believe the only way to allow User2 to be seen form A is to change SUG on B to a Security Local Domain but I never tested it because this was not possible for me. If the domains A and B are in the same forest maybe this is not needed.